# How can I properly render a JS app in Electron on a PC with 300% zoom?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am writing an application in [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) (a framework for building apps in JS). My teammates all have 100% zoom on their system display, and my machine has 300% zoom (this in Settings>Display>Scale and Layout). We have embedded a website into our app, and for my team it appears the same as in the browser: well centered. On my PC, the contents of the app are not centered and it becomes unusable as the login screen becomes out of view due to my system zoom settings. Is there any way to get the system zoom through JS and use it to resize the window? There may be a way to deal with this using CSS, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Please add code examples to show what your issue is. We need minimum reproducible code to be able to test it out.

Comment: Stop using pixels to size things. Consider using a relative size.

Comment: I'm guessing the OS is Windows? If the system zoom is kept in the registry, you might be able to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows to query it.